# Shift Register Alternatives

Tags: shift-register

Ben Eater's 8-Bit Computer  [project](https://eater.net/8bit/schematics) calls for 8 "4-bit D-type register". Is it ok to use the CMOS version, the CD4076BMTE4?http://bg-electronics.de/datenblaetter/Schaltkreise/CD4076B.pdf

I have heard that sometimes the voltage varies too much. The orignal design asks for the 74LS173. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54173.pdf

Also, can you use a bidirectional register, like the 74S194, and set it to go one way? http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LS194A

Lastly, can an 8 bit shift register IC, like the 74hc595, be used with four bits or does the chip require 8 bits to work properly?
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf

Sorry, for asking so many questions at once.

Comment: Post a link to a schematic.  TTL outputs do not always play well with CMOS inputs -- that's why 74HCT was invented.  So plopping a CD4000-series part into the middle of a TTL design is probably not a good idea.

Comment: But you haven't posted a link to the **schematic** of the board you're trying to build.  Not everyone here knows of Ben Eater, much less his 8-bit computer project.

Comment: I added it, but its a huge project. If you don't want to wade through it can you just go over the differences in those chips in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you consider making a change to something that someone else has spent ... not hours but months and perhaps years making sure it works right ... you need to be prepared to evaluate your change ideas, closely. And that means you need to understand how it works.

Ben Eater has gone to some length to reach out and teach the ideas he's applied, taken to a level almost anyone serious about the topic can follow even without much prior background. In your link to his web page, if you click on the "registers" link there, it will take you to five separate videos that take about an hour to listen to. Just on the topic of his register design.

He starts out talking about using 7474 D-type FFs but then points out that there's a need for tristating buffers, so he trots out the 74245 and a bunch of AND, OR, and NOT gate chips as well, all of which he has discussed in other (older) videos. However, in these videos he's discussing a much simpler approach using the 74173, which is actually ***designed*** from the start to operate as a register attached to a bus. It not only includes four D-type FF, but it also includes the AND/OR and enable logic required and it also includes the tri-stating ability for its outputs, as well. So it's pretty much everything all bundled into a nice, easy to use part.

The 74194 does NOT have the tri-stating outputs and it's not designed as a register for a bus, but for an entirely different purpose. You can't just poke around like that. Even if you could get the 74194 to hold values for you, you still wouldn't have the tri-stating capability. And you need that, as well. So you'd now have to change his logic involved in using the part, entirely. It's just wrong on its face.

One thing is sure. You aren't prepared to make your own decisions about swapping parts around like this. So don't.

You already have Peter's recommendation about the two families that kind of "hang together" in acceptable ways. But even then you still need to be wary. Stick with a single family unless you feel competent to do otherwise. Taking into account Peter's answer, you should read at least some of [An Introduction to and Comparison of 74HCT TTL Compatible CMOS Logic](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-368.pdf.pdf) where you will find the following two tables in "easy to read" comparison format:

[image]
[image]

HCT was designed to meet the TTL level standards at its inputs and do so with lower input current, but you can see that there are differences in the output voltage and current compliance specifications. It's not likely to bite you. But for example, the HCT output current compliance is symmetrical while the LS isn't. You need to be able to evaluate if this matters in some situation you are considering.

You might want to skim over the above intro-doc I linked above to see if anything catches your attention. Other than that? I'd stick to the plan. There's a lot of work ahead and it will be enough already just getting that much done and working right.

Comment: I wanted you to know that I thank both of you for your time in answering this and am especially glad you pointed out the tri-stating outputs part.

Comment: @Putvi I'm just happy you are engaging a project like this. I did almost this same thing (not the exact same thing, of course) in 1974 using wire-wrap boards when I was quite a bit younger. It's a very educational (and for me frustrating at times, of course) project and the experience will inform you in many different ways. Just make sure you have a very good power supply with adequate current compliance. (If you use the HCT family, it's likely you won't need quite so good of a supply.) Despite the LS family being lower power than their predecessor, they still draw current.

Comment: @Putvi This may not directly apply to you (I've no idea what options are available in your location), but Digikey sells (if you buy only one at a time and live in the US) the HCT173 at about 1/3rd the price they want for the LS173: USD 0.64 vs USD 1.55. You should check out your own supplier options and see which direction may be better for you.

Comment: I live in the US (IL) , but I ordered some of this stuff online and it took a long time to get and was broken when it arrived. I really do thank you for saying you are happy I am trying this, but I get frustrated when it takes a long time to get the parts and then spend hours putting things together to find the part didn't work.

Comment: @Putvi I'd probably do the same thing and get the same results, if I tried today. Back then, by the way, the prices took my breath away as it cost entire months' worth of salary to buy them. Relatively speaking, these are still cheaper than when I was buying them for this. Digikey won't send you broken or poorly packaged parts. Neither will Mouser. And I noticed that Jameco sells a kit that probably includes most of what you need: [420 pcs kit of 74LS](https://www.amazon.com/Jameco-Valuepro-Piece-Logic-Component/dp/B00B887Y9S). You also need lots of jumper wire!

Comment: Jameco is where I got the stuff the first time, tbh. I don't mean to bad mouth them, because the people were so nice, but like I said, I just get stressed out.

Comment: @Putvi Hmm. Sorry to hear that about Jameco. I have a special tool I use to straighten out the pins for DIP chips like this. But that tool is no longer being sold, and I'm hanging onto mine, so I can't recommend anything specific to help, there. If you receive a bad package (over Amazon, anyway) you can easily get it returned for a replacement or money back. Amazon can be vicious to their suppliers when a customer complains for any reason. But I get the stress about all this. Mostly, you'll need to find patience and a willingness to work through things one detail at a time to get to the end.

Comment: if I can take more of your time, how far along were you when you made the similar processor project? I mean how long had you been making electronic stuff?

Comment: @Putvi I was about 18 yrs old at the time. No electronics training of any kind then (or now.) I just read some magazines and made some stuff. For example, I'd designed and built a small Geiger counter and an AM crystal radio (I actually melted the lead and trapped a Galena crystal in it.) Mostly, I just got books and studied them. No family members or friends helped me study. Just did it on my own. It was a slow process and I had to go to various companies to ask to look through their garbage for boards and parts (except I had to buy the 74xx parts and the wire wrap sockets.)

Comment: @Putvi Probably the most expensive/difficult part for me at the time was the memory. Static RAM was crazy-expensive and I didn't know enough to use DRAM (it would be a few years more before I did.) I couldn't even afford the idea of 256 bytes of static RAM. So I was stuck with just 16 words of code and data.

Comment: I get you, how long did you study though? I started using chips and transistors lat last year. I wondered if I made it to a large project like this quickly.

Comment: @Putvi It's never too soon to try something like this. If you have a personal interest in logic and/or how computers work that motivates you, that's all that is needed. You'll do the rest. I don't recall precisely how much time I spent before, reading through the hardcover TTL data book. But I only became interested in computers end-of-1972 and learned assembly and BASIC over the following year. So I'd guess I spent perhaps a half-year before jumping off and attempting something simple? Today? Far fewer barriers exist now: low cost, good stuff to read, people to help over the web, etc. Easier.

Comment: I ordered that same book last week.

Comment: @Putvi You actually *ordered* the hardcover first edition? Cool. I got my softcover version in 1976 (2nd edition.) And there was a supplemental book, too, I got a little later (Can't recall the date for that supplement.)

Comment: I don't remember if it is hardcover, but several people who have done projects like this said its based off that and another book, so I ordered it used off Amazon.

Comment: @Putvi By the way, this conversation will be "deep 6'd" soon by the moderators. Just so you know. They bury them very deep in some chat place that makes it very much harder to communicate or to know about communication when it happens. They'll provide a link to it, though.

Answer (score 0):

In that project, I saw several 4 bit parallel-in/parallel-out registers - the '595 definitely won't work for those, as it is serial in/parallel-out.  The '194 probably would work, as it has parallel in and out - just ignore the shift capability.

That project seems to be designed with 74LS family parts.  You should stick with 74LS, although 74HCT should also work.

74HC and CD4000 parts will not work reliably with 74LS, as the input and output high levels for 74LS are lower than for 74HC and CD4000 CMOS parts.

74HCT has lower input thresholds so it should work with 74LS parts.

Comment: I wanted to thank both of you for taking the time to answer. I really do appreciate it.